# Send Object with Object attribute as file

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have a `Serializable` Object called Message and I want it to contain a music, I have the path of it.

I don't want to directly send a music using `inputStream/outputStream`, I want to put it in a message which I send.

**How is it possible to do that?**

Client code :

```
if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_SEND_MESSAGE)){
    String host = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRAS_GROUP_OWNER_ADDRESS);
    Socket socket = new Socket();
    int port = intent.getExtras().getInt(EXTRAS_GROUP_OWNER_PORT);
    Message lcm = (Message) intent.getSerializableExtra(DATA);
    Air.get().log("MessageService", "Send message: "+lcm.getClass().getSimpleName());
    ObjectInputStream inputStream;

    try {
        Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "Opening client socket - "+host+":"+port);
        socket.bind(null);
        socket.connect((new InetSocketAddress(host, port)), SOCKET_TIMEOUT);
        OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);

        oos.writeObject(lcm);

        oos.close();
        os.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, e.getMessage());
    } catch(Exception e){

    }
    finally {
        if (socket != null) {
            if (socket.isConnected()) {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // Give up
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the server part :

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8988);
Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "Server: Socket opened");
while (true) {
    Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
    Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "Server: connection done");
    InputStream is = client.getInputStream();
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);
    Message to = (Message) ois.readObject();
    if (to != null) {
        Log.d(to.toString(), to.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Put a message in what? In a separate object and output that?

Comment: No I want to send a MusicMessage (type:Message) which contains a music

Comment: Well I can already see that you've tried something. What errors are you currently getting?

Comment: In fact I don't have any error. I just don't know what object should contain my Message knowing I have the path of the music